# Discontinuity of a screw dislocation

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics

Consider a screw dislocation,

[image]

The displacement field is given by
$$u_{z}=\frac{b\cdot\theta}{2\pi}=\frac{b}{2\pi}\cdot\tan^{-1}(y/x)=\frac{b}{2\pi}\cdot\arctan(y/x).$$
And the strain field is derived by
$$\varepsilon_{yz}=\varepsilon_{zy}=\frac{b}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{b}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$$
My question is that the displacement seems discontinuous across the dislocation surface ($y=0$), so why it is still differentiable on the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is better to leave the displacement in polar coordinates, that is

$$u_z = \frac{b}{2\pi} \theta\, .$$

If you want to express it in cartesian coordinates you should use the function [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) instead of `atan`.

Also, in polar coordinates you have

$$\epsilon_{z\theta} = \frac{b}{4\pi r}\, .$$

We could read this as material points rotating in the same direction. This can be visualized in the following image.

[image]

The effect looks different because some of the points are moving upward and the others downward, but all of them are rotating and skewing in the same direction.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's the same in a polar coordinate system, consider a point at θ=0, the displacement could be 0 or b, as your figure shows. This means on the dislocation surface (i.e., θ=0), any adjacent points (on each side of the surface) will have a displacement difference of b, which makes the displacement field discontinouse.

Comment: I find in some textbook that the displacement 'step change' across the dislocation surface is plastic deformation, so the actual elastic displacement field is continuous at the surface and the total displacement field (discontinuous) is the sum of the elastic-displacement (continues) and the plastic-displacement (slip b). The strain and stress we calculated using the equation are elastic, there also exists another plastic component. I am not sure how to understand it properly. 

Rf: Dislocations in solids. Vol. 1. The elastic theory edited by F. R. N. Nabarro, pp42-44.

Comment: I will update the answer with a drawing.

Comment: yes, that explains why the 'slip' isn't an elastic deformation and doesn't take part in the elastic strain and stress. Excluding the 'slip' makes the remaining deformation elastic and continues. But I think we cannot directly differentiate the total displacement field without an explanation like this, really confusing.